# Distributed process updating a global/single variable in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

I'm in trouble trying to process a vast amount of data on a cluster.

The code:

```
val (sumZ, batchSize) = data.rdd.repartition(4)
  .treeAggregate(0L, 0L))(
    seqOp = (c, v) => {
      // c: (z, count), v
      val step = this.update(c, v)
      (step._1, c._2 + 1)
    },
    combOp = (c1, c2) => {
      // c: (z, count)
      (c1._1 + c2._1, c1._2 + c2._2)
    })

val finalZ = sumZ / 4
```

As you can see in the code, my current approach is to process this data partitioned into 4 chunks (x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>3</sub>) making all the process independent. Each process generates an output (z<sub>0</sub>, z<sub>1</sub>, z<sub>2</sub>, z<sub>3</sub>), and the final value of z is an average of these 4 results.

This approach is working but the precision (and the computing time) is affected by the number of partitions.

**My question** is if there is a way of generating a "global" z that will be updated from every process (partition).

Comment: What does `this.update(c, v)` do? And how exactly precision is affected? You seem to use `Long` so FP issues don't apply.

Comment: @user9613318 the code has been simplified to be illustrative enough without giving too much detail. In the real example, v is a vector and z is a vector containing the gradient of each dimension of v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** There is not. Spark doesn't have shared memory with synchronized access so no true global access can exist.

The only form of "shared" writable variable in Spark is [`Accumulator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators). It allows write only access with commutative and associative function.

Since its implementation is equivalent to `reduce` / `aggregate`:

- Each partition has its own copy which is updated locally.
- After task is completed partial results are send to the driver and combined with "global" instance.

it won't resolve your problem.